# Mac "command" to change the background color in a terminal

Tags: command-line, mac, colors

I want to change the background color of my terminal. `setterm` doesn't work on a mac? I did find a command which changes the prompt to include the ANSI code?

```
PS1="\h \w$ \e[0;32m"
```

But it doesn't take effect immediately, and I want to have it be part of a script which will launch other programs.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a way to send ANSI color codes to change the background color in the emulated color terminal, that should work in any terminal emulator that emulates a color terminal? Or are you looking for something specific to macOS's built-in "Terminal.app" terminal emulator (but might not work with other third-party terminal emulator apps like iTerm)? Or would you be fine with either one?

Comment: @Spiff I don't think it needs to work elsewhere, just in my mac terminal, but I would prefer a solution that is compatible with *nix desktops and servers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create an [AppleScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Script) script to change the colors of the current [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)) tab. You can use the **Script Editor** found in **Applications/Utilities** to create the script. One way to change the colors is to use the [color schemes that you could manually select for the Terminal window](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2015/04/26#terminal-colors-change), but perform the selection in a script. E.g., you could create a script with the following commands using the **Script Editor**

```
tell application "Terminal"

   set current settings of window 1 to settings set "novel"

end tell
```

You could substitute "grass", "ocean", "Red Sands", etc., instead of "novel". Inside the **Script Editor** click on **File** and then select **Save**. Save the script wherever you wish to place it as a .scpt file. Assuming you named the file terminal-colors and placed it your ~/Documents directory,  from a Terminal window tab, you can run the script using the [osascript](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/man/man_osascript.html) command `osascript ~/Documents/terminal-colors.scpt`

Alternatively, you can set specific background colors of your choosing using values you can find for specific colors at [colors.csv](https://gist.github.com/avillafiorita/9e626ce370e1da6c6373). E.g., if you wanted to have a hot pink background, you could use the following commands in your script, instead of the ones above:

```
tell application "Terminal"
   set background color of window 1 to {65535, 33667, 49601}
end tell
```

This is an MacOS solution that wouldn't be portable to Linux/Unix.

You can see other settings you can change for a Terminal window by opening the Terminal "dictionary" in the **Script Editor**. Click on **File**, select **Open Dictionary**, scroll through the list of dictionaries until you see **Terminal.app** then click on it to select it and then click on the **Choose** button. Within the dictionary, click on **Terminal Suite** then **tab** to see settings you can change for individual Terminal window tabs.

Comment: This is working, but it's a little annoying (having to create extra applescripts), and (as you mentioned) isn't portable. Thanks!

Comment: @McKay You don't need to create AppleScript files, osascript can run AppleScript from a string using `-e`. `osascript -e "tell application…`

Answer (score 0):

Creating an applescipt and then making an alias to it can make this a quick process once set up.

Step1 - Create applescript, save to e.g. ~/Documents/scripts

> vi ~/Documents/scripts/changeBGcolor-1green.scpt
>   tell application "Terminal"
>      set current settings of window 1 to settings set 1
>   end tell
>
> vi ~/Documents/scripts/changeBGcolor-2grey.scpt
>   tell application "Terminal"
>      set current settings of window 1 to settings set 2
>   end tell

1 an 2 shown above but etc. for numbers going up.

Step2 create alias and source file.

> vi ~/.bash_profile
>   alias cgreen="osascript ~/Documents/scripts/changeBGcolor-1green.scpt"
>   alias cgrey="osascript ~/Documents/scripts/changeBGcolor-2grey.scpt"
>
> source ~/.bash_profile

I couldnt find a list of what the numbers actually were so I tested the first 10 and will describe below.

1 = green
2 = grey
3 = red
4 = black
5 = alternated colors for some reason when command repeated (I found useful)
6 = light black
7 = tan
8 = blue
9 = off white
10 = pale yellow

So for example in the shell afterwards

> cgreen
>   would change the background to green